# Find duplicate rows by field using typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm using [typeorm](https://typeorm.io/#/) with Postgres.

Having a table with columns (id, name), I want to find all names that are duplicate in the table

E.g. If I have:

```
id | name
1  | Foo
2  | Bar
3  | Foo
4  | Arthur
```

I want to get `Foo`

In SQL I usually do the following:

```sql
SELECT name FROM my_table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1;
```

However, I'm not sure how to write the same query (or similar) with typeorm.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing but in where part.

```js
getConnection().getRepository(MyTable)
   .createQueryBuilder('my_table')
   .select('my_table.name')
   .groupBy('my_table.name')
   .where('COUNT(my_table.name) > 1')
   .getRawMany();
```

Comment: we cannot use aggregate function in where clause

`having` clause will work here.

Comment: it works for MySQL, but in other SQL you are right, not all of them support this approach.

Comment: Doesn't work with Postgres

Answer (score 0):

```
getConnection().getRepository(MyTable)
   .createQueryBuilder('my_table')
   .addSelect('my_table.name')
   .groupBy('my_table.name')
   .where('COUNT(my_table.name) > 1')
   .getManyAndCount();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**